# Sass installation error using npm install -g sass

Tags: node.js, sass

I just try to install sass and i always get this error everytime i run sass, sass --version, I just update the npm and node to the latest version but still no luck

```
C:\Users\axel mhar valdepena\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:1997
    throw H.e(H.cH(a,function(e,f){return e.replace(/[^<,> ]+/g,function(g){return f[g]||g})}(z+y,init.mangledGlobalNames)))},
    ^

TypeError: Instance of 'dz': type 'dz' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'
    at Object.e (C:\Users\axel mhar valdepena\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:1629:3)
    at Object.c (C:\Users\axel mhar valdepena\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:1997:9)
    at uZ.dart.fh (C:\Users\axel mhar valdepena\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:10234:19)
    at Object.tK (C:\Users\axel mhar valdepena\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:1597:69)
    at Object.fy (C:\Users\axel mhar valdepena\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:5690:28)
    at dart.Cd (C:\Users\axel mhar valdepena\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:7278:10)
    at Object.run_ (C:\Users\axel mhar valdepena\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:7266:42)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\axel mhar valdepena\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sass\sass.js:8:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
```

Comment: Did you try `npm cache clean --force` and  `npm rebuild node-sass`.

Comment: i tried npm cache clean it didn't work,  but it's okay now i just install node-sass

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

- remove the directory `sass` from the path `C:\Users\axel mhar valdepena\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\`
- then in the console, run again  `$ npm install -g sass`